# LONG data type in database migration with Room

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am going to migrate my database from version 1 to version 2, I need to delete columns from some tables and I know that for this I need to follow these steps:

1. Create the new table
2. Copy the data
3. Remove the old table
4. Change the table name to the correct one

With Room I was able to define my columns as Long data type without any problem. But for the migration I will use this method:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE user (userid LONG, id_event LONG, category INTEGER, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(userid))");
```

But I don't know if using this method to create the table I can define LONG type values, if I can't, what is the procedure to follow?

Comment: There are only 5 affinities in sqlite... It doesn't matter if its long or integer.. For integer type you can always store up to 8 bytes integer